# Python Recursive Directory Listing While Changing Directory Name

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I've got a question that I need some help from you python wizards

This is the directory structure that I'm working with, but their names are encrypted. Now, I'm trying to list these directories and files while decrypting their names.

```
rootfolder
-subfolder
--subsubfolder
---file_in_subsubfolder
--file1_subfolder
-subfolder2
-file1
-file2
```

This is my code currently

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    dirname = os.path.basename(root)
    decrypted_dirname = decrypt(dirname)

    print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(root),decrypted_dirname)

    for f in files:
        print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(root), decrypted_dirname, decrypt(f))
```

My output then looks like this.

```
rootfolder/decrypted_subfolder
rootfolder/subfolder/decrypted_subsubfolder
rootfolder/subfolder/decrypted_subsubfolder/decrypted_file_in_subsubfolder
rootfolder/decrypted_subfolder2
rootfolder/decrypted_file1
rootfolder/decrypted_file2
```

Issue is, the "subfolder" in the 2nd and 3rd line is not decrypted. How can I adjust the code such that I can decrypt the folders and list them properly, recursively.

Comment: How are they encrypted?

Comment: And how are you decrypting it?

Comment: its a custom function. I've edited my example, to add an example

Comment: You can interactively debug your code with the `pdb` module. It might be a good place to start since your decryption function is working for the other levels. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: if you notice I'm doing the decryption on the fly, so I'm not editing the file or folder names while listing them. I'm trying to figure out how I can list them on the fly/

Comment: How I would handle this: have a Python dictionary that maps encrypted directory names to decrypted versions. Add to it as needed. When you need to print a multi-level directory entry, split it, and feed each portion through the dictionary, combining the result.

Answer (score 0):

As @user3757614 suggested one approach would be to use a dictionary to keep track of the "decrypted root path" and reuse it

Example :

```
decrypted_path_map = dict();
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    dirname = os.path.basename(root)
    decrypted_dirname = decrypt(dirname)
    parent_path =  decrypted_path_map.get(os.path.dirname(root),os.path.dirname(root))
    decrypted_path_map[root] =  os.path.join(parent_path,decrypted_dirname)

    for f in files:
        print os.path.join(decrypted_path_map[root],decrypt(f))
```